# Magento mysql tuning - Is my.cnf corrcet?

Tags: mysql, magento

We have 24 CPU and 32 GB RAM and would like to know if `my.cnf` is set correctly.

Many thanks:

---

> connect_timeout = 300
>
> innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 128M
>
> innodb_autoextend_increment = 8M
>
> innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
>
> innodb_file_per_table = 1
>
> innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 600
>
> innodb_thread_concurrency = 50
>
> interactive_timeout = 300
>
> join_buffer_size = 8M
>
> key_buffer = 32M
>
> max_allowed_packet = 64M
>
> max_connections = 500
>
> myisam_sort_buffer_size=128M
>
> open_files_limit = 65535
>
> query_cache_size = 64M
>
> query_cache_type=1
>
> read_buffer_size = 2M
>
> read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
>
> skip-networking
>
> sort_buffer_size = 256M
>
> table_cache = 1024
>
> thread_cache_size = 64
>
> thread_concurrency = 96
>
> tmp_table_size = 256M
>
> wait_timeout = 300
>
> query_cache_limit = 4M
>
> max_heap_table_size = 256M

Comment: please inform about: version of PHP, MySQL and Magento itself !

Comment: Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 - PHP Version 5.3.25 - MySQL version 5.1.70-cll

Answer (score 0):

Set correctly?  NO
REMOVE the following list so DEFAULTS can support your effort from [mysqld] section

```
sort_buffer_size
read_buffer_size
read_rnd_buffer_size
join_buffer_size
```

to improve(reduce) response time.

Why would you intentionally read 16M for read_rnd_buffer_size when you could get the data you need with the DEFAULT of 256K ?

Comment: @caniko  Do you still use this system?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Innodb_buffer_pool_size is very less as compare to size of RAM. 
It should ideally be 70% of size of your RAM for best performance.